# Unable to catch the success response IE

Tags: angularjs, api, internet-explorer, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I have an application wherein it should work both in chrome and IE. API call using resource(ngResource) is working fine in chrome/Firefor - able to get response in success block when api is success. But in IE11 same api is going into error block. Please let me know if any configuration is required in resource factory.

Comment: Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I test [this sample](http://embed.plnkr.co/egjodS/index.html) on my side in IE 11, it seems that everything works well. Besides, I suggest you could use F12 developer tools to check whether it display some error.

Comment: ResourceService.js

var Resource = $resource(routeUrl + `/records`, {}, {
 update: ResourceFactory.prepareDefaultResource({
  method: 'POST',
  url: routeUrl + `/update`,
  isArray: false,
  cache: false,
 }),
});

return Resource;




controller

this.provider = ResourceService;
this.provider.update(params, (response) => {
 console.log("success block");
}, (error) => {
 console.log("error block");
});